# Filtering a Data Frame with Very specific Requirements

Tags: r

[Fifa2 dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qS8fo.png)First, I am not a developer and have little experience with R, so please forgive me. I have tried to get this done on my own, but have run out of ideas for filtering a data frame using the 'filter' command.

the data frame has about a dozen or so columns, with one being Grp (meaning Group). This is a FIFA soccer dataset, so the Group in this context means the general position the player is in (Defense, Midfield, Goalkeeper, Forward).

I need to filter this data frame to provide me this exact information:
the Top 4 Defense Players
the Top 4 Midfield Players
the Top 2 Forwards
the Top 1 Goalkeeper

What do I mean by "Top"? It's arranged by the Grp column, which is just a numeric number. So, Top 4 would be like 22,21,21,20 (or something similar because that numeric number could in fact be repeated for different players). The Growth column is the difference between the Potential Column and Overall column, so again just a simple subtraction to find the difference between them.

```
#Create a subset of the data frame
library(dplyr)
fifa2 <- fifa %>%   select(Club,Name,Position,Overall,Potential,Contract.Valid.Until2,Wage2,Value2,Release.Clause2,Grp) %>% arrange(Club)
#Add columns for determining potential 
fifa2$Growth <- fifa2$Potential - fifa2$Overall
head(fifa2)

#Find Southampton Players
ClubName <- filter(fifa2, Club == "Southampton") %>% 
  group_by(Grp) %>% arrange(desc(Growth), .by_group=TRUE) %>% 
  top_n(4)
ClubName

ClubName2 <- ggplot(ClubName, aes(x=forcats::fct_reorder(Name, Grp),
                                  y=Growth, fill = Grp)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", colour = "black") +
  coord_flip() + xlab("Player Names") + ylab("Unfilled Growth Potential") +
  ggtitle("Southampton Players, Grouped by Position")
ClubName2
```

That chart produces a list of players that ends up having the Top 4 players in each position (top_n(4)), but I need it further filtered per the logic I described above. How can I achieve this? I tried fooling around with dplyr and that is fairly easy to get rows by Grp name, but don't see how to filter it to the 4-4-2-1 that I need. Any help appreciated.

Sample Output from fifa2 & ClubName (which shows the data sorted by top_n(4):

[fifa2_Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ggQt.png)

Comment: Can you update your question with sample data from `fifa2` using `dput`

Comment: I don't have access to the R code now, so I'll have to do it tonight.

Comment: I added some screenshots above. Hopefully, that helps.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the most elegant solution, but hopefully it works :)

```
# create dummy data
data_test = data.frame(grp = sample(c("def", "mid", "goal", "front"), 30, replace = T), growth = rnorm(30, 100,10), stringsAsFactors = F)

# create referencetable to give the number of players needed per grp
desired_n = data.frame(grp = c("def", "mid", "goal", "front"), top_n_desired = c(4,4,1,2), stringsAsFactors = F)
# > desired_n
# grp top_n_desired
# 1   def             4
# 2   mid             4
# 3  goal             1
# 4 front             2

# group and arrange, than look up the desired amount of players in the referencetable and select them.
data_test %>% group_by(grp) %>% arrange(desc(growth)) %>% 
  slice(1:desired_n$top_n_desired[which(first(grp) == desired_n$grp)]) %>% 
  arrange(grp)

# A bit more readable, but you have to create an additional column in your dataframe

# create additional column with desired amount for the position written in grp of each player
data_test = merge(data_test, desired_n, by = "grp", all.x = T
                  )
data_test %>% group_by(grp) %>% arrange(desc(growth)) %>% 
  slice(1:first(top_n_desired)) %>% 
  arrange(grp)
```

Comment: #######
Manchester <- filter(fifa2, Club == "Manchester City") %>% 
  group_by(Grp) %>% arrange(desc(Growth)) %>%
  slice(1:desired_n$top_n_desired[which(first(Grp) == desired_n$grp)]) %>%
  arrange(grp)
Manchester

Comment: Error in 1:desired_n$top_n_desired[which(first(Grp) == desired_n$grp)] : 
  argument of length 0

Comment: I am following the logic, but that is the error I get. Any ideas?

Comment: Do the strings in desired_n$grp match the strings in fifa2$Grp? all(fifa2$Grp %in% desired_n$grp) should deliver true. If not, there is a Grp string in fifa2 which is not in desired_n.

Comment: I think that did it! I had to adjust the strings bc I had them as "Defense","Midfield","GK","Forward"   It seems to print out the desired info. Thanks a lot everyone! I'll keep on checking the results to make sure they are accurate, but at first glance it looks OK.